# Como faço para formatar os valores em reais da minha aplicação Android?

Tags: android, netbeans, number-format

Quero que os valores do editText apareçam em reais.. como faço para formatar dentro das minhas condições atuais de código?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ProdutoDao;
import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Produto;


public class CadProdutos extends Activity {

static final int SALVAR = 0, EXCLUIR = 1, LIMPAR = 2;
EditText edId, edDescricao, edPrecoDeVenda, edPrecoDeCusto, edPercDeLucro;
ProdutoDao prodDao;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.cad_produtos);
    edId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdId);
    edDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdDescricao);
    edPrecoDeVenda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPrecoDeVenda);
    edPrecoDeCusto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPrecoDeCusto);
    edPercDeLucro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPercDeLucro); 


    Produto produtoRecebido = (Produto) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Produto");
    if (produtoRecebido != null) {
        montaTela(produtoRecebido);
    } else {
        montaTela(new Produto());
    }

    Button btn1Salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSalvar);
    btn1Salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Produto pro = new Produto();
            pro.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            pro.setDescricao(edDescricao.getText().toString());
            pro.setPrecoDeCusto(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPercDeLucro(Double.valueOf(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPrecoDeVenda(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString()));

            if (pro.getId() > 0) {
                getProDao().alterar(pro);
            } else {
                getProDao().inserirProduto(pro);
            } 
            ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Salvo com Sucesso",
                    ToastManager.INFORMATION);

        }
    });


        Button btnLimpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLimpar);

        btnLimpar.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            montaTela(new Produto());
        }
    });

    Button bt2Excluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2Excluir);
    bt2Excluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Produto pro = new Produto();
            pro.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            pro.setDescricao(edDescricao.getText().toString());
            pro.setPrecoDeCusto(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPercDeLucro(Double.valueOf(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPrecoDeVenda(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString()));

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadProdutos.this);
            builder.setTitle("Deseja Excluir?");
            builder.setMessage("O produto será deletado!");

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    getProDao().excluir(pro); 
                    montaTela(new Produto());
                   ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Produto Excluído",
                    ToastManager.INFORMATION);

                } 

            }); 

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(CadProdutos.this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();


        }
    });
}



private void montaTela(Produto produto) {
    edId.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getId()));
    edDescricao.setText(produto.getDescricao());
    edPrecoDeVenda.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeVenda()));
    edPrecoDeCusto.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeCusto()));
    edPercDeLucro.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPercDeLucro()));
}

public ProdutoDao getProDao() {
    if (prodDao == null) {
        prodDao = new ProdutoDao();
    }
    return prodDao;
}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
public String formatarValor(double value) {
    NumberFormat formatoBr = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
    return String.valueOf(formatoBr.format(value));
}

edPrecoDeVenda.setText(formatarValor(produto.getPrecoDeVenda()));
```

Comment: Ok, mas como eu aplico no meu código ? Sou novo na área e estou com alguma dificuldade.. agradeço a compreensão.

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke resposta editada